# Работа с файлами и строками C++

Tags: c++, файлы, классы, fstream

Дано: файл с данными, например:

> иванов иван муж. 20 программист 850.50.

Нужно взять из файла строку, а из строки слова и эти слова передать в класс(string, string, string, int, string, float).

```
void getAccess() {
  ifstream file("./endUnemployed.txt");
  while(file) {
    string str;
    getline(file, str);
    cout << str << "\n";
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Вот на этом я застрял. Есть идеи как преобразовать string в разные типы, или лучше сделать строку char* и находить пробел как разделитель?

Comment: Вы ровно так же можете искать пробел как разделитель в std::string ;-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можешь примерно показать, опыта работы со строками нет а сроки горят :c

Comment: Примерно - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ и дальше уже смотрите что вам нужно.

Comment: Попадется Вам какой нибудь `Главный бухгалтер` или `Заместитель начальника цеха` и амбец Вашему парсеру

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я заполняю данные так, что такого не будет :D

Comment: Если пример не учебный, то старайтесь с самого начала разделить поля. Так ошибок и проблем будет меньше. То есть лучше сразу заполнять в программе/форме c отдельными "окошечками". Если требуется иметь промежуточный текст, то хотя бы заполните в каком-то экселе/либреофисе, потом сохраните текст в CSV. Там уже многословные поля аккуратнее сформированы.

Comment: @AlexTitov это курсовая работа, я делаю в текстовом файле потому что так требует преподаватель, наверное буду использовать | как разделитель, но всеравно спасибо, будет нужда сделаю так)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову для вашего случая:

```
while(file) 

{
    std::string str, delimiter = " ";
    std::getline(file, str);

    pos = str.find(delimiter);
    std::string str_1 = str.substr(0, pos);
    str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

    pos = str.find(delimiter);
    std::string str_2 = str.substr(0, pos);
    str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

    pos = str.find(delimiter);
    std::string str_3 = str.substr(0, pos);
    str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

    pos = str.find(delimiter);
    int i_1 = std::stoi(str.substr(0, pos));
    str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

    pos = str.find(delimiter);
    std::string str_4 = str.substr(0, pos);
    str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

    pos = str.find(delimiter);
    float f_1 = std::stof(str.substr(0, pos));
    str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

В переменных str_1, str_2, str_3, i_1, str_4, f_1 будет содержаться все, что необходимо для передачи в класс.

Comment: `error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
     int sex = stoi(str.substr(0, pos));` - вот только инт не работает)

Comment: спасибо огромное то, что нужно) чтобы не было ошибки нужно компилировать с параметром -std=c++0x `g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp 
`

Answer (score 0):

После считывания строки связываешь поток ввода-вывода с  stringstream. stringstream это библиотечный класс, вроде как находится в sstream.

Далее оттуда читаешь как с обычного потока. Перевод во внутреннее представление осуществляется с помощью функций sto*(), которые объявлены в заголовочнике string.

Я написал про связывание ввода-вывода потому, что не понял, принципиально ли тебе считывать построчно данные из файла. Если там куча таких строк и это не так важно, то просто помни, что считывание в строку идет либо до пробела, либо до символа конца строки/файла.